# Display all value with character

Tags: java

I have a list containing Strings. I want to display all the values of this list in an array of strings with a line break after each value and start with -.

```
private List<String> usersName = new ArrayList<>();

private void setUsersTest(){
    usersName.add("1");
    usersName.add("2");
    usersName.add("3");
    usersName.add("4");
    usersName.add("5");
    usersName.add("6");
    usersName.add("7");
    usersName.add("8");
    usersName.add("9");

    //Exemple
    /**
     * List of users:
     * - 1
     * - 2
     * - 3
     * - 4
     * - 5
     * - 6
     * - 7
     * - 8
     * - 9
     */
}
```

Comment: Why would you use an "array"?

Comment: Without an array: `usersName.stream().forEach(n -> System.out.printf("- %s%n", n));`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
for(String user: userName){
    System.out.println("- "+user);
}
```

Hope this helps